# ERROR value error 'transform' must be an instance of 'matplotlib.transform.Transform'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi no idea whats going on here was following a tutorial and have no sytax errors or warnings in code but when i run i get this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-d2d08b3c451f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/FILES1/BIZ/CURRENCIES/PROG/STUFF/testapps/spyder/ProgsForSteve/plottest.py', wdir='C:/FILES1/BIZ/CURRENCIES/PROG/STUFF/testapps/spyder/ProgsForSteve')

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/FILES1/BIZ/CURRENCIES/PROG/STUFF/testapps/spyder/ProgsForSteve/plottest.py", line 20, in <module>
    plt.plot(x, y, label = label1)

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3347, in plot
    ax = gca()

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 984, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 601, in gcf
    return figure()

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 548, in figure
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 160, in new_figure_manager
    fig = fig_cls(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 366, in __init__
    self.bbox = TransformedBbox(self.bbox_inches, self.dpi_scale_trans)

  File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 1050, in __init__
    raise ValueError("'transform' must be an instance of "

ValueError: 'transform' must be an instance of 'matplotlib.transform.Transform'
```

Here is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as t

incur1 ='nzd'
incur2 = 'usd'
time = t.datetime
first_exRtRate1 = 0.712

label1 = (incur1+ '/' +incur2)
label2 = (incur2+ '/' +incur1)

x = []
y = []
x2 = []
y2 = []
plt.ion()
plt.plot(x, y, label = label1)
plt.plot(x2, y2, label = label2)
plt.xlabel ('Time')
plt.ylabel ('Ex Rate')
plt.title (+incur1+ '/' +incur2+ '/nEx Rate Data')
plt.legend()


time = t.datetime
x.append(time)
y.append(first_exRtRate1) 

plt.show()
```

I tried additionally importing matplotlib by itself to ensure matplotlib.transform was there but that was no good.

I have no idea how to resolve the transform issue, or even where to start.

I presume this is an issue where its trying to use transform to create the plot but its not getting it from matplotlib should import transform or something?

Comment: I get a different error.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Have you run the exact code you posted?

Comment: yes that is throwing the error and copied directly out of spyer

Comment: and is the entire file

Comment: Which line are you getting your error on?

Comment: edited to show full list

Comment: There error I am seeing happens after the line you are getting an error in.  Suggest you check you versions...  GL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167306/discussion-between-goulouh-anwar-and-stephen-rauch).

Comment: Make the example more minimal. Does it occur when not using `plt.ion()`, would it occur when plotting non-empty lists? Name the version of matplotlib in use.

Comment: I did a less complicated version like that last night just tested and it worked hunch that it was starting with an un-populated list. Wlll let you know at a later time was filling in some down time on an earlier part of the project. Thank you for your suggestions and help. It was version 2.2.2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and then I simply restarted Spyder and the issue was gone.

Another thing that could be a workaround is to create a new virtual environment using

```
conda create --name myenv
```

and install spyder in the new environment using

```
conda install spyder
```

and consequently opening Spyder, go to **Tools > Preferences** and change the Python Interpreter to the Python.exe file present in the new environment folder, and then run the code.